# React-Router: except for props.children, can I pass extra variables to parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

If I have the following in my router:

```
<Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
    <Route path="path/one" component={App1} hasTitle={false} />
    <Route path="path/two" component={App2} hasTitle={true} />
</Route>
```

I will get either `App1` or `App2` in `MainLayout` as `this.props.children`. But can I get some other customisation in MainLayout, by passing, for example, `hasTitle=false` or `hasTitle=true` in sub routes like the above?

Comment: if you want to get props from route , you can use this,props.route.hasTitle

Answer (score 0):

Use [cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) to pass additional props down to the child, instead of `{this.props.children}` in the `MainLayout` write

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {hasTitle:true})}
```

Comment: Be noted to iterate over the children with `React.Children.forEach` or `React.Children.map` before the clone if there are multiple contained elements in  `this.props.children`.